# how to get label value in mvc 3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

**In Model:**

```
 public class DataViewModel
{
    public IList<RowsCollection> Rows { get; set; }

    public PaiementMethod PaiementMethod { get; set; }

}
public class RowsCollection
{
    public string ID { get; set; }  
    public string Question { get; set; }
}

public enum PaiementMethod
{
    Cash,
    CreditCard,
}
```

In the **Controller** - Index ActionResult I have return my Model and render its into **view** page something like :

```
      @model WebNexpo.Controllers.DataViewModel
     @using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "page", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "saves"}))
      {
        foreach (var item in Model.Rows)
        {
           @Html.Label(item.Question)
           <label for="paiement_cash">
            Cash</label>
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.PaiementMethod, "Cash", new { name = "paiement_cash" + @item.ID + "", id = "radioID" + @item.ID + "", Group = "Group" + @item.ID + "" })
        <label for="paiement_cc">
            Credit card</label>
         @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.PaiementMethod, "CreditCard", new { name = "paiement_cc" + @item.ID + "", id = "radioname" + @item.ID + "", Group = "Group" + @item.ID + "" })

         }
       <input id="Saveser" type="submit" value="" class="button1" />
   }
```

in submit form Action Event :

```
     [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Save(DataViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //want to read all the label which selected rediobutton.
              means suppose 4 question render on page and user have selected only 2
             question of the answer.so How can accomplish here?  
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index", new {value = "123"});
    }
```

Comment: RowsCollection contains no id in your code are you aware of that? I will also remove the html name attribute in the radio buttons that sometimes gives some issues with the built-in default model binding

Comment: in my project i have add this..here just i am not define..any ways  Html page render perfectly which is i did code in `.cshtml(razor)`.but my doubt is how can i get in `controller` when submit Action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's some inconsistency here. You are rendering 2 radio buttons for each row so you probably want to reorganize your view model into:

```
public class DataViewModel
{
    public IList<RowsCollection> Rows { get; set; }
}

public class RowsCollection
{
    public string ID { get; set; }  
    public string Question { get; set; }
    public PaiementMethod PaiementMethod { get; set; }
}
```

and then:

```
@model DataViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "page", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "saves"}))
{
    for (var i = 0; i < Model.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        <div>
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Rows[i].ID)
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Rows[i].Question)
            @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Rows[i].Question)

            @Html.Label("payment_cash" + i, "Cash")
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Rows[i].PaiementMethod, "Cash", new { id = "payment_cash" + i })

            @Html.Label("payment_cc" + i, "Credit card")
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Rows[i].PaiementMethod, "CreditCard", new { id = "payment_cc" + i })
        </div>
    }
    <input id="Saveser" type="submit" value="" class="button1" />
}
```

and finally:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(DataViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // model.Rows[0].PaiementMethod will contain the selected payment method for the first question
        // model.Rows[1].PaiementMethod will contain the selected payment method for the second question
        // ...
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index", new { value = "123" });
}
```

or if you want a single payment method you could keep your view model as is but then leave the radio buttons outside of the loop in your view. Like that:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "page", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "saves" }))
{
    for (var i = 0; i < Model.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        <div>
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Rows[i].ID)
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Rows[i].Question)
            @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Rows[i].Question)
        </div>
    }

    @Html.Label("payment_cash", "Cash")
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.PaiementMethod, "Cash", new { id = "payment_cash" })

    @Html.Label("payment_cc", "Credit card")
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.PaiementMethod, "CreditCard", new { id = "payment_cc" })

    <input id="Saveser" type="submit" value="" class="button1" />
}
```